# How to use multiple paramenter in run command in autohotkey v2

Tags: autohotkey

I updated my autohotkey from v1 to v2

```
appskey::run,Wscript C:\folder\script.vbs "netsh wlan disconnect"
return
```

the above command working good in v1 to break in v2
I tried :

```
appskey::run "Wscript C:\folder\script.vbs" "netsh wlan disconnect"
```

throws error -there is no script engine for file extension ".vsnetsh"

```
appskey::Run "Wscript C:\folder\script.vbs netsh wlan disconnect"
```

it open in background but not working

Please correct the above code so that it run for multiple parameter.

Comment: Try removing the Quotation Marks altogether for something like `appskey::run,Wscript C:\folder\script.vbs netsh wlan disconnect`. This works for me when testing it with a [batch script that spits back out its input parameters](https://pastebin.com/3Bt6YghU), but I am not sure if it will work as well with wscript.

Comment: He's writing v2, you can't remove quotes. Though I wouldn't recommend quote-less for v1 either. And that would also pass in 3 arguments as opposed to just one argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v2 everything is evaluated as an expression.
What you're doing in your run command here:
`run "Wscript C:\folder\script.vbs" "netsh wlan disconnect"`
is concatenating two string together, so the first (and only) argument the `Run` function receives is:
`"Wscript C:\folder\script.vbsnetsh wlan disconnect"`.
So you're trying to run a file called `script.vbsnetsh` and pass in two arguments into it, `wlan` and `disconnect`.

And here:
`Run "Wscript C:\folder\script.vbs netsh wlan disconnect"`
You're running the correct script, but you're passing in three arguments, `netsh`, `wlan` and `disconnect`.

What you're trying to do, is run a file called `script.vbs`, and pass in just one argument into it, that argument being `netsh wlan disconnect`.
Your argument contains spaces, so you have to wrap the argument around in `"`s to indicate it's just one argument, just as you do in your v1 legacy script.

So the correct version would be:

```
Run "Wscript `"C:\folder\script.vbs`" `"netsh wlan disconnect`""
```

You escape quotation marks with `` `" `` in v2<sup>[(docs)](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm)</sup>.
And the added quotation marks around your file path aren't needed because your file path doesn't have spaces in it, but it very easily could have, so I added them in for a better demonstration.